# C#, GraphApi multiple file attachments >4MB

Tags: c#, email, facebook-graph-api, large-files

I have the following issue, everything up until this point is working but the final bit (below) is causing an exception and I can't work out why.

```
MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(package);
ChunkedUploadProvider chunkedUploadProvider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(mySession, graphClient, myStream, -1);
await chunkedUploadProvider.UploadAsync(3);
```

the await is giving me an error of "The stream does not support reading."
anyone got any ideas?
thanks

Comment: i'm wondering if its something to do with the '-1' i'm using which defaults to 5mb and the file collection (as a zip) is around 4.2mb...

Comment: nope, not that, went to the default (320 * 1024) and it just errors quicker :), I've checked the stream (myStream) and its readable and seekable....

Answer (score 0):

gave up and have used HttpRequestMessage instead. Works fine.

Comment: this can be closed